# How to run testStep in another project using SoapUI testrunner in command line?

Tags: groovy, cmd, soapui, test-runner

We have few soapui projects each sending testrequests at different web services. The Groovy script that executes the tests is however for the most part identical for each project. Therefore we decided it would be good with regard to easy versioning and maintenance to keep the common script in separate "dummy" project ("TestWSScript-soapui-project.xml") with one testsuite/case (Autotest/Test) with only one testStep (Groovy script named "Run").
The idea is to have one project for each WebService (say WS1-soapui-project.xml) which has testSuite with one TestCase. Within this TestCase will be

- Groovy test step to set WS specific properties and call the universal script from TestWSScript-soapui-project.xml
- Request test step to call the webservice and perform assertions
- Ending Groovy test step.

This works from within SoapUI, but I want to run the tests from Windows command line (batch file for automatization purposes). Here I ran into a problem: when invoking testrunner from command line with

```
set "SOAPUI_FOR_TEST_DIR=..\..\..\programs\SoapUI-5.6.0"    
"%SOAPUI_FOR_TEST_DIR%\bin\testrunner.bat" -sAutoTest -r -a -j -I "..\resources\WS1-soapui-project.xml"
```

it does not load whole workspace with all SoapUi projects. Therefore the following script (in WS1-soapui-project.xml/AutoTest suite/Test TestCase) that should run testStep from project TestWSScript-soapui-project.xml/AutoTest suite/Test TestCase returns *Null* (more specifically "Cannot invoke method getProjectByName() on null object")

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.project.ProjectFactoryRegistry
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProjectFactory

def workspace = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace
def testProject = (workspace==null) ? 
  ProjectFactoryRegistry.getProjectFactory(WsdlProjectFactory.WSDL_TYPE).createNew("TestWSScript.xml") :
  workspace.getProjectByName("TestWSScript")
if(!testProject.open && workspace!=null) workspace.openProject(testProject)


// Connect to the test step in another project.
def prj = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName('TestWSScript')
tCase = prj.testSuites['AutoTest'].testCases['Test']
tStep = tCase.getTestStepByName("Run")

// Call the test runner and check if it can run the specified step.
def runner = tStep.run(testRunner, context)
```

The called script just loops through parameters read from csv file and calls request step. It is irrelevant for the problem I need to solve as the issue happens before the script is called.

Is there even a way to achieve what we want? We are using the free version of SoapUI-5.6.0.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're already running it from Windows command line, _(assumed cmd.exe)_, why are you using `cmd.exe /C ` to launch another cmd.exe instance? Also if you're running a batch file, as those are already processed by cmd.exe, why use cmd.exe at all, as opposed to just running the batch file directly. I also note that there's no doublequotes in your provided command-line, and you've not given us any idea whatsoever, of the content of any of the variables it contains, or how those were defined. We need to be able to replicate your issue, please read [mcve] for more information on what that means.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried to clear it a bit of the unneeded parameters and add better explanation of the process. The cmd.exe was inherited from my colleague and has no explicit meaning so I removed it. Is it clear now?

Comment: You still should have two sets of double-quotes on the second line; one enclosing the .bat file path, and one enclosing the .xml file path.

Comment: Why? There is no space in the path so quotes are not necessary. It works perfectly fine this way. Nevertheless, I added them so it is absolutely universal, if you need it.
More importantly, this call is NOT where the issue occurs, you are nitpicking on something that does not help solve my problem.

Comment: Because you should always double-quote as best practice. In the case of your provided code, because you are using relative paths, there is no way of determining if that relative path will ever include spaces, and/or other poison characters. No robust code should make assumptions, hence 'best practice'. BTW, this is the comment section, don't complain about nitpicking, I'm commenting, in order to help you to make improvements and learn. Also you should remove ```%cd%\```, the default starting location for a relative path is already the current directory, so it serves no purpose.

Comment: OK, I get that, but it is still unsolicited advice. If only you had at least formulated your comments like advices. I came here to solve a problem, that line of code (that I did not even wrote) is mostly irrelevant for the issue and I put it there just for the sake of clarity of what is called and how. Do you have anything to say to the actual issue at hand, please?

Comment: You posted a question which uses inherited, _(read as unsolicited)_ code, with no request whatsover for 'no unsolictied advice'; and therefore that advice is implied. Your decision is simply whether you wish to action, or ignore, that advice, not to complain that you've received it.

Comment: @MatějMorávek, Not sure what your use case is. In general, it is best practice to have each and every test case is independent and avoid dependencies. May be you want to re-design tests to be independent if possible. Workspace is limited to UI and should be avoided. One can't access it while executing the tests from commandline `testrunner`.

Comment: @Rao The script I want to run goes through a folder of test requests (individual for each web service/soapui project we are testing) and loads it into a request step then runs it. Which folder is used is decided based on the project name, therefore the script itself is identical for each project, so the projects are independent on each other, they just use the same script. We ant to keep it separate so when we change anything on it, it will affect all projects without the need for copy-pasting it. It will also make versioning much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I suggest in your case.

- Instead of a separate project for just one groovy script, create a library out of it.
- Create a class and methods as needed. Use method arguments or class members in case if you are passing data from the callers.
- Use your existing script, convert them into class, methods.
- Create the class(es) based on the need.
- It can be programmed either `java` or `groovy`
- Compile the class(es) and create library
- Copy this library under `%SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\ext` directory
- Now you can just call those methods in any project. No more dummy project is required.
- Good thing is all the projects are independent.

Here is [blog](https://rupz.me/soapui-cookbook-bonus-recipes/1-how-to-develop-add-and-use-a-custom-groovy-library-in-soapui/) content created by Rupert Anderson, one of the SoapUI export and Author.

```
Steps

1.Create the following directory structure

soapuilib/src/main/groovy/custom

2.Get some Groovy code

For this example, I have knocked together a simple script to generate sequential ids. It may be of little practical use, but I wanted something with a simple public static method to call. Since the method is static, there will be no need to instantiate the class before calling it in step #8.

[groovy title=”SequentialIdGenerator.groovy”]
package custom

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong

public class SequentialIdGenerator {
public static final long counterSeed = 1000
public static final String prefix = "id"
private static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(counterSeed)

public static String nextId() {
return prefix + counter.incrementAndGet()
}
}
[/groovy]

    create the above script as a text file called SequentialIdGenerator.groovy
    copy it to soapuilib/src/main/groovy/custom

3.Create Gradle build script

For this part, there are plenty of options to build the code and package it, such as Maven, Ant or just running the right shell commands! The following minimal Gradle script allows us to compile and package the code as a jar in one easy statement.

[code language=”groovy”]
apply plugin: ‘groovy’

version = ‘1.0’

jar {
classifier = ‘library’
manifest {
attributes ‘Implementation-Title’: ‘SoapUI Sample Groovy Library’, ‘Implementation-Version’: version
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile ‘org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.1.7’ //Matches Groovy in SoapUI 5.2.1
}

[/code]

    Create the above Gradle script as soapuilib/build.gradle

INFO: Groovy Version – (At time of writing) The current version of Groovy is v2.4.6, but SoapUI 5.2.1 ships with Groovy 2.1.7. If you try to compile with a Groovy version 2.3+ and use it with SoapUI, you will see an error popup and log message in like ‘org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling‘ – see http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/groovy-2-3-5-out-with-upward-compatibility for more details and options. Basically, you can still use the latest Groovy version, but will need to include an additional groovy-backports-compat23 dependency!

5.Compile it & Create jar file

Now we’re ready to use the Gradle script to compile the sample script from step #2 and package it as a jar file.

    Open a shell/command prompt at soapuilib/
    gradle clean build jar

You should then see output like:

[bash]

tests-MacBook-Pro:soapuilib test$ gradle clean build jar
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.499 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

[/bash]

and our new library jar file created under the directory:

soapuilib/build/soapuilib-1.0-sample.jar

6.Add jar file to SoapUI

To make our new Groovy library jar available for use in SoapUI, it should be added in SoapUI Home under the following external library directory:

SoapUI ext Directory

Or the Windows equivalent e.g. C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\ext

7.Verify jar file is imported

When SoapUI is restarted, you should see the following log entry indicating that the jar file has been successfully added to the SoapUI classpath:

SoapUI ext Lib Loaded
8.Call the code

Our SequentialIdGenerator has a public static method nextId() that we can call, so to do this we can either import the class (Example 1)  or just prefix the class with its package (Example 2). See below:

    Example 1 – Call from Groovy TestStep:

[code]
import custom.*

log.info SequentialIdGenerator.nextId()
[/code]

Gives output like:

[code]

Thu May 12 16:49:20 BST 2016:INFO:id1001

[/code]

    Example 2 – Call from Property Expansion:

[code]

${= custom.SequentialIdGenerator.nextId()}

[/code]
```

EDIT:
Here is the sample code with `context, log` variable access.

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/nmrao/c489a485bbe3418cf49d8442f9fb92eb.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much. I have very limited experience with creating libraries, but elsewhere I found that this might be the best way. That blogpost looks really helpful, I hope I can fiddle with it to do what we need.

Comment: You already have code in place how to do the same in you groovy script test step. Here just need put that in organized format by converting into class.

Comment: If you have dificulty to convert, please add it, will see if can help. If this is helpful, you  can mark it accept the solution. By the way, the above is not in god format, but blog is clear.

Comment: I made work the example presented on the blog, now trying to rework that with my code. The main problem I ran into was the use of _log_ and _context_ in my script - the gradle would not even compile the library as these are not defined and I need to pass them in and out of the script (the _context_ is needed in the request body and assertion).
I will try to clean and shorten the script so it can be added here, but maybe tomorrow

Comment: There are two way to handle them. Either declare them at class level and initialize while creating the object or pass them to the method arguments. See [this](https://gist.github.com/nmrao/c489a485bbe3418cf49d8442f9fb92eb) example

Comment: YES, it works! Thank you, thank you, you have no idea how much you helped me!

Comment: @MatějMorávek, Glad to know that you could proceed. Wish you good luck with future projects and adding new lthings to your library and automate more stuff.